# Matching a color in SVG with feColorMatrix

Tags: css, svg, vector-graphics, colormatrix, svg-filters

I created a drop shadow in SVG using `SourceAlpha` for the shadow, so its plain black. Using `feColorMatrix` I reduced the opacity a bit, but still it wasn't looking as I wanted - I want the color of the shadow to match a specific color value. So I took a more in depth look at `feColorMatrix`.

Now I don't use `SourceAlpha` as source for the shadow, but `SourceGraphic`. As my vector image is plain white aka `rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)`, I can calculate the color of the shadow like that:

```
<feColorMatrix in="the-shadow" result="color-out" type="matrix"
                values="0.0157 0      0      0 0
                        0      0.3059 0      0 0 
                        0      0      0.7765 0 0 
                        0      0      0      1 0  "/>
```

The outcome should be a dark blue shadow aka `rgba(4, 78, 198, 1)`.

Actually this is working and I believe the calculations are all correct, but when creating a shadow with CSS3 using the same color, there is a noticeable difference: The SVG filter seems to render the color a bit too light. Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

feColorMatrix like most filters operates in the linearRGB colour space. If you want an sRGB colour, Try setting [color-interpolation-filters](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#ColorInterpolationFiltersProperty)="sRGB" as an attribute on the feColorMatrix.

```html
    <svg width="100%" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    
    viewBox="0 0 640 480" height="100%"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    
    <filter id="cm">
    
    <feColorMatrix in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                    values="0.0157 0      0      0 0
                            0      0.3059 0      0 0 
                            0      0      0.7765 0 0 
                            0      0      0      1 0  "/>
    
    </filter>
    
    <filter id="cmRGB">
    
    <feColorMatrix color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" in="SourceGraphic" type="matrix"
                    values="0.0157 0      0      0 0
                            0      0.3059 0      0 0 
                            0      0      0.7765 0 0 
                            0      0      0      1 0  "/>
    
    </filter>
    
    <rect width="100%" height="50%" fill="white" filter="url(#cm)"/>
    
    <rect y="50%" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" filter="url(#cmRGB)"/>
    
    </svg>
```

It sure looks different to me on Firefox.

Comment: Good idea, I didn't even know about that attribute, but it didn't change anything to my eyes.

Comment: Just wanted to say that this worked for me when trying to use feColorMatrix as a colorizer--setting all the in RGBs to 0 and using the 5th column vals to set the color. Yay!

Comment: Here's [a handy tool that converts RGBA to feColorMatrix](http://andresgalante.com/RGBAtoFeColorMatrix/). More details about it [here](http://andresgalante.com/random/2016/07/09/rgba-to-fecolormatrix.html).

Answer (score 1):

Whilst my answer repeats the same idea, what I have to add is too much for a comment.

I don't know for sure, what is `linearRGB` in the standard, but I expect it to be, erm, *linear*. I.e. white color transformed with (darken-twice)

```
R | ½ 0 0 0 0
G | 0 ½ 0 0 0
B | 0 0 ½ 0 0
A | 0 0 0 1 0
```

should result in the same color as `rgb(50%, 50%, 50%)`, shouldn't it?

As well as black color transformed with (ligthen-twice)

```
R | ½ 0 0 0 ½
G | 0 ½ 0 0 ½
B | 0 0 ½ 0 ½
A | 0 0 0 1 0
```

expected to be the same 50% gray.

But what I actually see as a result is much lighter than expected, color picker shows `#BCBCBC` instead of `#808080`. On the other hand, `color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"` makes the result correct (checked a macbook and a win10 ASUS notebook with default settings).

https://jsfiddle.net/7wvy57fq/2/

Comment: Thanks, so it's "[a] (light energy linear) linearized RGB color space", which isn't very good naming, cause this leads to leaky abstraction: as a programmer I'd like to work with RGB abstraction, w/o thinking about actual perceived color. On top of that this is inconsistent: all graphic editors work linearly in RGB (probably after photoshop), all other matrices works linearly.